# Why does my function that executes a MySQL query gives errors when called using ttk.combobox's postcommand

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have this program that is connected to a phpmyadmin MySQL database. It has a combobox whose values I want to update whenever the drop-down arrow is clicked. I use the combobox's postcommand parameter to call a function that executes a query and updates the values. Here is my code simplified:

```
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Program')
root.geometry('600x600+100+100')

def load_combobox(conn, cbox):
    query = 'SELECT nama_sopir FROM sopir'
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cbox.config(values=result)

try:
    with connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        password = '',
        database = 'sinar_express_database'
    ) as conn:
        frame1 = Frame(root)
        frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        # I want to call the function on postcommand. This calls the function but an error occurs
        sopir_cbox = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state='readonly', postcommand=lambda : load_combobox(conn, sopir_cbox))
        sopir_cbox.pack()
except Error as e:
    print(e)

root.mainloop()
```

and this produces an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Winston\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Documents\Usaha Papa Mama\Program Uang Jalan\Baru\stackoverflow.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    sopir_cbox = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state='readonly', postcommand=lambda : load_combobox(conn, sopir_cbox))
  File "d:\Documents\Usaha Papa Mama\Program Uang Jalan\Baru\stackoverflow.py", line 11, in load_combobox
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Winston\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1025, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available
```

I've tried calling the function separately as seen below and it works! However, I want to update the values everytime the dropdown is clicked not just once.

```
        sopir_cbox = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state='readonly')
        load_combobox(conn, sopir_cbox)
```

I'm still quite new to programming so any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: GUI frameworks works different then `input()` - Combobox doesn't wait for your decision - it only inform tkinter what to display in window and `mainloop()` starts window - so you see window after it exit ` with connect()`. You have to assing function to `Combobox and run ` with connect()` inside this function. Or you should put `root.mainloop()` inside ` with connect()`

Comment: Since you have used `with connect(...) as conn:`, so the database connection will be closed after the `with` statement.  Therefore when `load_combobox()` is executed, the database connection has been already closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GUI` frameworks don't work like `input()` which wait for your decision. `Combobox` (and other widgets) does't wait for your decision. It only inform `tkinter` what it has to display in window - and code moves to next line - to `mainloop()` which displays window.

So you see window after it exits `with connect()` and when you select option then code is already outside `with connect()`. You have to use `with connect()` inside `load_comobox`.

```
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def load_combobox():
    try:
        with connect(
                host = 'localhost',
                user = 'root',
                password = '',
                database = 'sinar_express_database'
            ) as conn:
            query = 'SELECT nama_sopir FROM sopir'
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                sopir_cbox.config(values=result)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

# --- main ---

root = Tk()
root.title('Program')
root.geometry('600x600+100+100')

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

# I want to call the function on postcommand. This calls the function but an error occurs
sopir_cbox = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state='readonly', postcommand=load_combobox)
sopir_cbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Or you would have to put `mailoop()` inside `with connect()`

```
with connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '',
    database = 'sinar_express_database'
) as conn:
    frame1 = Frame(root)
    frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    # I want to call the function on postcommand. This calls the function but an error occurs
    sopir_cbox = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state='readonly', postcommand=lambda : load_combobox(conn, sopir_cbox))
    sopir_cbox.pack()

    root.mainloop()
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

---

But here I see one problem - you can't use `sopir_cbox` inside `ttk.Combobox(...)` because it doesn't exits yet. Code first executes `ttk.Combobox(...)` and later it creates variable `sopir_cbox = ...` but you need `sopir_cbox` inside `ttk.Combobox(...)` when `sopir_cbox = ...` was not created yet. You would have to do it in two steps

```
sopir_cbox = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state='readonly')
sopir_cbox["postcommand"] = lambda : load_combobox(conn, sopir_cbox)
```